# need a return value from the stored procedure

Tags: c#, web-services, ado.net

I am trying to update a SQL Server table using a stored procedure which is called in a web service. Here I need a return value from the stored procedure so that I can send true or false to the user regarding the update confirmation.

I am using C# as the language and ADO.Net architecture for connecting and manipulating SQL Server Tables.

I am also using `SQLDataConnection` (`System.Data.SqlClient`).

Comment: you can use try catch in store proc and if it fails rollback and return false http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: thanks sam...but i m nt suppose to change the procedure..

Comment: Hey Sam     just go through the procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[Update]
(
 @a int,
 @b int,
 @c int
)

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

 UPDATE UpdateTable
  SET
   a=@a,
   b=@b,
   c=@c,
   
 WHERE c=@c
        
 IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RETURN 0
 END  
--calling another Insert Procedure
 Exec InsertTable  @a, @b

 IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RETURN 0
 END  

 COMMIT TRANSACTION
 RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
END

Answer (score 1):

You can create stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROC ReturningProc
AS
BEGIN
IF (@SomeCondition)
      SELECT 1

SELECT 0
END
```

And you can call it using sql command object as:

```
object retval = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a SqlDataReader object to read the results. In a nutshell, like this:

```
var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
while(reader.Read())
{
var result = reader[0];
//Respond to result.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend the Entity framework (EF) route as it does all the coding for you. All you have to do is point it to your database and select the necessary tables. It allows you to use Linq which internally translates to SQL Queries.

If you are new to this, I would recommend the database first approach highlighted in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907).

If you are persistent about using a stored procedure, you can still use EF to interact with your stored procedure as described in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) and this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx).

In case you do not want to use EF at all and prefer writing the database handling logic yourself, you can refer to this [link](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx)

Hope this gives you some clarity and something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure something like this:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate]
  @b BIT OUT

 AS
    if(some condition)
       SET @b = 1
    else
       SET @b=0
 GO
```

retrive value in c# like this

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.Bit);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
string retunvalue =  Convert.ToBoolean(sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value);
```

and you have set value of @b before calling stored procedure, other wise SP will throe exception.